# How exclude record from eloquent where no relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have two tables "inventory" and "sell_records" relationship. Each product in inventory has many sell records. I need to order all products by the latest sold record. But some products don't have any sell records. So I need to exclude these products from the eloquent.

This is a script I have.

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)
                                        ->join('inventory_sell_records', 'inventory_sell_records.product_id', '=', 'inventory.id')
                                        ->groupBy('inventory_sell_records.product_id')
                                        ->orderByRaw("max(inventory_sell_records.created_at) $order_by")
                                        ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: What error you get by running this query or result?

Comment: There is no error, I just getting all records even these that don't have related records in the other table. But I need to exclude these records without the selling record in the query.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a query with inner join but in laravel style you have to do...

1. Create hasMany relation in inventory model.
2. Change your query like below

`$inventory = Inventory::withCount('sells')->where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)->orderBy('sells_count', 'desc')->paginate(100);`

**In Query sells indicates the hasMany relation name**